# Haskell function definition, missing argument?

Tags: function, haskell, definition

```
module Tf0 where

all' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all' p = foldr (&&) True . map p 

main :: IO()

xs = [1,3,5,7,9]
xs1 = [1,3,11,4,15]

k1 = all' (<10) xs
k2 = all' (<10) xs1
k3 = all' (<10)

main = print k1
```

Questions:

1. In the function definition (`all' p = foldr (&&) True . map p`) there is no list as an input while the function Type shows a list as an input (`[a]`), yet trying to check the function (see bellow `k1`, `k2`, `k3`) shows that a list is needed.
2. How can the function be defined without the list?

Comment: Writing `f x = g x . h x` is the same as writing `f x y = g x (h x y)`, by definition of the composition operator `.`. The first style is referred to as "point-free style" (or, jokingly, point-less style).

Comment: One word: currying.

Answer (score 4):

One of the fundamental aspects of Haskell is that *conceptually* a function **always takes one argument**. Indeed take for instance the function `(+)`:

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

(technically it is `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, but let us keep things simple).

Now you can argue that `(+)` takes two arguments, but conceptually it takes one argument. Indeed: the signature is in fact

```
(+) :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

So you feed it **one integer** and now it returns a function, for instance:

```
(+) 5 :: Int -> Int
```

So you have, by giving it a `5`, constructed a function that will add 5 to a given operand (again a function that takes one argument).

Now applying this to your question, the signature of `all'` is in fact:

```
all' :: (a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> Bool)
```

So if you apply `all'` with one argument, it **returns a function that maps a list `[a]` to a `Bool`**. Say for the sake of argument that we set `p` to `\_ -> True`, then we return:

```
foldr (&&) True . map (\_ -> True) :: [a] -> Bool
```

so indeed a function that takes a list `[a]` and maps it on a `Bool`. In a **next phase** you apply a list to **that** (returning) function.

In other words, functional programming can be seen as a long chain of specializing a function further and further until it is fully grounded and can be evaluated.

Haskell only provides this in an elegant way such that you do not have to think about functions generating functions. But conceptually, this happens all the time. Given you want to implement a function `f :: a -> b -> c`, you can do this like:

```
f x y = g (x+1) y
```

(with `g :: a -> b -> c`), but you can also decide to leave a parameter out, and define it as:

```
f x = g (x+1)
```

since `g (x+1)` will return a function that can apply with the `y` eventually.

Comment: I'd avoid the section `(5+)` for this, since it exploits a special syntax, and instead use plain application `(+) 5` which follows the spirit of the argument.

Comment: @chi: that is indeed a good suggestion: modified. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanations, however,I would like to get an answer for the following: Given (from your example that two (different?) functions:f x y = g (x+1) y and f x = g (x+1), how does the second function( f x = g (x+1)) "Know" that a second parameter (y) is expected?

Comment: @Atir: because Haskell knows the type signature of `g` and `g :: a -> (b -> c)` means `g (x+1)` will "collapse" to `g (x+1) :: b -> c`, so it reasons it needs a `b` to generate a `c`.

Comment: @Atir when you define `f x = g (x+1)`, you get two types inferred, `f :: Num x => x -> a` and `g :: Num x => x -> a`. Depending on *later/other* uses of both/either `f` and `g` in your code, that `a` may get instantiated yet further; in particular, if `g x y` is found, `a` would become `b -> c` for some `b` and `c`. You can even try this at the GHCi prompt: try `let f x = g (x+1) ; g y = g (y-1)` and then e.g. `let f x = g (x+1) ; g y z = g z (y+1)` (with `:set +t` enabled to see the types). *This* is what is referred to by "every function has one argument".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem terminology: we "bind" a value to a *name*; we *apply* a value to a function.

Comment: @WillNess: usually when people are rather strict about terminology I think about [this xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/747/). But nevertheless in order to keep the blood pressure of my fellow Haskellers acceptable, (modified) ;P

Comment: using wrong terms quickly gets very confusing unless a reader *knows* already what you mean. newcomers *don't*, yet.

Comment: @WillNess: yeah, I was joking, I hope you got that :) I hope you're not angery, usually I appreciate people being able to put things in perspective :)

Comment: :) ___________________